# Find all the numbers from one billion integers which differs from the given number by only within 3 bits

Tags: algorithm

This is a question i heard from an interview. 
suppose you have one billion integers and each integer is represented by 64 bits. Now give you any integer m， how to find a number in the files which differs from the given number by only less than 3 bits(maybe 0 bit, 1 bit, 2 bits, or 3 bits) in O(1) time?  can anybody give me some clue??

Comment: Can the bits be anywhere in the 64 bits?

Comment: "Now give you an integers m， how to find the numbers in the files which differs from the given number" - do you have only one number `m` or several (`m`) numbers to check against?

Comment: yes, it is okay, dude

Comment: i have make some mistake here, you are given only one int

Comment: @Hexinwei "i have make some mistake here" - then edit the question.

Comment: If the numbers are not ordered or indexed in any way, then you obviously have to look at each number, so O(1) is not possible. Reading the entire contents of a file, or list, or array is always an O(n) operation.

Comment: it is not about look at every numbers,  it is about query the number satisfy the constraint, we can do some preprocessings on  the integers like hashing   and solve the problem in O(1)

Answer (score 2):

The numbers that you are searching for are quite few - in the order of `64^3`. My suggestion is - once you are given the number, compute all numbers that differ  from it in at most 3 bits and put them in a hash table. Then iterate over the input and for each input number check if it is in the hash table. This approach will have expected complexity `O(n)` where `n` is the number of input values.

Comment: it is not okey dude,  bruteforce is one method but not well,  check it.

Comment: I am not suggesting any brute force also I am quite sure this is the best you can do in terms of performance

Comment: My "brute-force" is just as much brute-force as is yours, since both have to traverse entire list, both yielding O(n) complexity. Nonetheless hashing complicates things a lot not to say finding those 64 ^ 3 numbers! Another things 64^3 is 262144, meaning it is not really a constant in practise.

Comment: Ivaylo Strandjev's solution can be combined with a pre-sorting (and maybe pruning) of the search space. You can then do a binary search to find the position in the list where your number would fit in and search right and left of that position. After the initial sorting (which takes `O(n log n)`), you can find the solution rather quickly (`O(log n)` for binary search and then a constant maximum of `64^3` lookups).

Comment: Last time I checked I only had 4gb ram :( Not really sure how I can binary search the list

Comment: @Slizzered but it is more costly as one has to iterate over 64 bits

Answer (score 1):

This algorithm has lower bound O(m). You have no other choice but to brute-force the list of all numbers and compare them with your number.

You can do comparison by how many bits x and y differ as:

```
z = x ^ y
result = count_number_one_bits(z)
```

Final code if you are given list of numbers A and number x would be:

```
for y in A:
  z = x ^ y
  test = count_number_one_bits(z)
  if test <= 3:
    yield y
```

Should you be given numbers one by one and you are given number y. You can check it with just the inner loop:

```
z = x ^ y
test = count_number_one_bits(z)
if test <= 3:
  yield y
```

Comment: obviously it is not working well , suppose every time i give you a new number,  you will always need to iterate through all the numbers in the file. i want to find an algorithm that can finish this task in O(1)， how can u solve it in O(1)， dude.

Comment: Than you for pointing that out. You just execute part in the loop. Check the edit :)

Comment: @Hexinwei please add more details into your question, so you have more than one query, not just one number `m`?

Comment: No need to thank me Hexinewi at StackOverflow :) just upvote and accept the answer :)

Comment: I think the ideal solution would be using hash table,  hash table will be better than the Xor solution, but i donot know how to design my hash function

Comment: Xor solution will be 100% simpler and faster to hash table solution. Xoring and counting number of ones is simpler and faster to calculating hash function and making look-up. Furthermore my solution is deterministic.

Comment: For multiple queries, you will need to iterate through the input file again and again?

Comment: No? You just xor new number and calculate ones.

Comment: Xor new number with?? each number in the input file or I am wrong?

Comment: Trung,  U have got the point, and this is the bottleneck of Xor solution

Comment: O(64 ^ 3) is indeed O(1) :D Good luck iterating over all subsets of size 3 and than you will have to xor for each one of those anyways.

Comment: Just use a binary search, for those input numbers, you don't need to iterating through all of them

Answer (score 1):

I have another idea for preprocessing that can reduce your search-space: for each of the integers, count the number of 1 bits. Sort them according to that number and keep 64 indexes (each pointing to the first number with 64 1-bits, 63 1-bits etc.). This preprocessing could be done using quicksort (doesn't require additional space if you sort in-place) with some custom comparison operator.

Now when you get your integer m, count the 1-bits and iterate only through the search space that has `n-3` up to `n+3` 1-bits. In that area, you can apply @Riko's solution.

Assuming you are dealing with a uniform distribution, this will reduce your search space to a factor of `7/64`. Of course, you have the preprocessing, which will take `O(n log n)`, but that will pay off when you have multiple lookups.

#### Edit:

based on the comment of @andrewjs, I want to highlight other data structures that be better than the quicksort approach

- Just count the number of bits and put the numbers into 64 buckets. Kind of a hash-map approach. Requires only `O(n)` in time, but might be a bit more memory-hungry, depending on the initial data structure. Has the same lookup time as the quicksort approach.
- Do the bucket approach, but remove duplicates. Will be slower than the simple bucket solution since you have to do comparisons inside the bucket for each new element, but might improve search speed if you could remove a lot of duplicates.

Comment: Your suggestion is to sort by "number of 1 bits". There will be a large number of comparisons of numbers which are equal. Instead of sorting, you could just split up the numbers into 64 different buckets, which are internally not sorted. Doing this partitioning would be O(n).

Comment: That is correct. It is basically a tradeoff between time and space, since the bucket solution might require some additional memory depending on the data structure of your input.

Comment: how about using bitmap of size O(2^32), and store all the numbers in the the bitmap. when a test number come in, you just compute all possible numbers(C(64, 3)) by reversing three bits in the test number for example, and then check against the bitmap/

Comment: oops, mistake here, you need bitmap of size 2^64,  i still think hash is the best to solve such problem